# error adding a new field to active admin only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I created the migration to add two new fields to the database, run rake db: migrate, added the name of the fields in project.rb inside the admin folder. It works in development perfectly and even saves the fields, but when I move it to the server in production it gives me the following error on the server:

```
[2019-12-11T22:00:51.534672 #15667]  INFO -- : [ddc2376a-4f4b-4744-be87-bde2ff699b2f] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 315ms (ActiveRecord: 37.3ms)
F, [2019-12-11T22:00:51.535812 #15667] FATAL -- : [ddc2376a-4f4b-4744-be87-bde2ff699b2f]   
F, [2019-12-11T22:00:51.535846 #15667] FATAL -- : [ddc2376a-4f4b-4744-be87-bde2ff699b2f] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `location' for #<Project:0x00007fa6d4beeee8>):
F, [2019-12-11T22:00:51.535960 #15667] FATAL -- : [ddc2376a-4f4b-4744-be87-bde2ff699b2f]     1: insert_tag renderer_for(:new)
F, [2019-12-11T22:00:51.535982 #15667] FATAL -- : [ddc2376a-4f4b-4744-be87-bde2ff699b2f]   
F, [2019-12-11T22:00:51.536001 #15667] FATAL -- : [ddc2376a-4f4b-4744-be87-bde2ff699b2f] app/admin/project.rb:66:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
[ddc2376a-4f4b-4744-be87-bde2ff699b2f] app/admin/project.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
I, [2019-12-11T22:00:51.819833 #15667]  INFO -- : [4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 190.122.220.221 at 2019-12-11 22:00:51 +0000
F, [2019-12-11T22:00:51.820622 #15667] FATAL -- : [4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0]   
F, [2019-12-11T22:00:51.820663 #15667] FATAL -- : [4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):
F, [2019-12-11T22:00:51.820685 #15667] FATAL -- : [4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0]   
F, [2019-12-11T22:00:51.820709 #15667] FATAL -- : [4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:149:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:415:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
[4a176034-3ddd-40cf-8b59-017915796ee0] /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

This is my project.rb inside the admin folder:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do
  actions :all
  permit_params :title, :end_time, :content, :extract, :picture, :user_id, :brand_name, :payment_amount, :link, :is_link, :location, :job_type

  filter :id
  filter :identifier
  filter :title
  filter :end_time

  # list configuration
  index do
    column :id
    column(:picture) { |project| image_tag(project.picture.url(:thumb), :width => "40") }
    column :title do |project|
      url = url_for :controller => '/project', :action => 'show', :identifier => project
      link_to project.title, url
    end
    column :extract
    column :end_time
    actions
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :id
      if project.picture.present?
        row(:picture) { |project| image_tag(project.picture.url(:thumb)) }
      end
      row :identifier
      row :title
      row (:content) { |post| raw(post.content) } 
      row :extract
      row :end_time
      row :created_at
      row :updated_at
      row :user_id
      row :brand_name
      row :payment_amount
      row :link
      bool_row :is_link
      row :location
      row :job_type

    end
  end

  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :title
      f.input :content
      f.input :end_time, as: :datepicker,
        datepicker_options: {
          min_date: 3.days.ago.to_date
        }
      f.input :picture, :as => :file, :hint => f.object.picture.present?\
        ? image_tag(f.object.picture.url(:thumb))
        : content_tag(:span, "no cover page yet")

      f.input :user_id, :as => :select, :collection => User.where("plan_id = 4").collect {|user| ["#{user.name} #{user.last_name}", user.id] }
      f.input :brand_name
      f.input :payment_amount
      f.input :link
      f.input :is_link, :as => :select, :collection => [["True",1],["False",0]]
      f.input :location
      f.input :job_type
    end
    f.actions
  end

  controller do
    defaults :finder => :find_by_identifier
  end

end
```

apparently it is not taking the new "location" field, what could I be missing?

Comment: Reduce to a [mre].

Comment: Did your migration run successfully on production? Perhaps include your migration code with your question.